# Can you search html attributes using wildcards with ruby nokogiri

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I know you can search text in html using wildcards.  Can you search for attribute values in html using wildcards with nokogiri

e.g., suppose I want to search for classes with value `*session*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use xpath contains() function to search the document. Something like:

```
doc.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., 'session')]]").each do |ele|
  # something
end
```

This search returns all the elements with any attribute whose value contains the string 'session'.

Comment: Since he specifically wants classes, `@class` may be better than `@*`

Comment: Note that using `contains()` alone like this will match `class="bad-session"`.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem few days ago - notice spaces around class values.

```
find(:xpath, "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' icon-edit ')]")
```