# How can I do a wildcard search with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to get rid of all `data-` attributes in a document. If my document looks like

```
<div id="person" data-name="John Smith" data-age="32" data-location="UK">...</div>
```

I want to strip out the data to just leave

```
<div id="person">...</div>
```

I've tried a lot of combinations, and can a least get to things like `data-name` with

```
doc.xpath('//@data-name')
```

but sometimes, there will be more `data-?` properties, and I'd like to avoid manually adding them all. [This SO answer is close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593489/can-you-search-html-attributes-using-wildcards-with-ruby-nokogiri), but it's not returning anything for me when I try

```
doc.xpath("//*[@*[contains(., 'data-')]]")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all attributes whose name starts with `data-`:

```
//@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-')]
```

Answer (score 1):

That answer you found was too deeply nested, try it this way:

`doc.xpath('//*[contains(., "data-")]')`

Comment: hmm, that will also select elements with `data-` in the text, or attributes of child notes, child text, etc.

Comment: you're right--it got all the data- but i hadn't accounted for that edge-case, thank you